Center of group rings.
I tried to prove the following problem from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra 3rd Edition (Exercise 13(b) of Section 7.2):
Let $\mathcal{K}_{1}, \dotsc, \mathcal{K}_{r}$ be the conjugacy classes of $G$ and for each $\mathcal{K}_{i}$, let $K_{i}$ be the element of $R G$ that is the sum of the members of $\mathcal{K}_{i}$. Prove that an element of $\alpha \in R G$ is in the center of $R G$ if and only if $\alpha = a_{1} K_{1} + \cdots + a_{r} K_{r}$ for some $a_{1}, a_{2}, \dotsc, a_{r} \in R$.
I got stuck with this problem not because it's difficult to solve but because I don't know how to write my solution without making it look ugly. But after hours of thinking, I was able to write my solution in this manner:
The converse directly follows from Exercise 13(a) of Section 7.2.
Let $\mathcal{K} = \{ k_{1}, \dotsc, k_{m} \}$ be a conjugacy class of $G$, and let $\alpha = r_{1} k_{1} + \cdots + r_{m} k_{m}$, where $r_{i} \in R$ for all $i$. Let $g \in G$ such that $k_{j} = g^{-1} k_{1} g$, where $j = 1, \dotsc, m$. If $\alpha$ is in the center of $R G$, then $g \alpha = \alpha g$, which implies that $r_{1} g^{- 1} k_{1} g + \cdots + r_{m} g^{- 1} k_{m} g = g^{- 1} \alpha g = \alpha = r_{1} k_{1} + \cdots + r_{m} k_{m}$. Since conjugation by $g$ on $\mathcal{K}$ is bijective, then $r_{1} = r_{j}$. But since $j$ is arbitrary, then $r_{1} = \cdots = r_{m}$.
Now, let $\alpha = L_{1} + \cdots + L_{r}$, where each $L_{i}$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal{K}_{i}$ in $R$. If $\alpha$ is in the center of $RG$ and $g \in G$, then it must mean that $g^{-1} L_{1} g + \cdots + g^{- 1} L_{r} g = g^{- 1} \alpha g = \alpha = L_{1} + \cdots + L_{r}$. But since $g^{-1} \mathcal{K}_{i} g = \mathcal{K}_{i}$ for each $i$, then we have $g^{- 1} L_{i} g = L_{i}$, which implies that $L_{i} g = g L_{i}$. Hence, by the above observation, we have $L_{i} = a_{i} K_{i}$ for some $a_{i} \in R$.
However, I feel like I left many gaps. Is this concise enough? How would you solve it in a concise manner?

I guess $G$ is a finite group, $R$ is a commutative ring, and $RG$ is the group algebra of $G$ ?

@AAAL yes, I forgot to mention that. $R$ also has $1$, if that's relevant.

This site is not a proof checking machine. Please check the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

Also the question how to determine the center of the group ring is of course a duplicate. Please use site search.
